# Passing data between threads (non main thread to OS main thread) in GTK4

Tags: c++, gtk

I am building a GTK application using GTK4. I am stuck with the problem on how to pass some data between threads in GTK. To be specific, I am presenting the problem in detail.

I have a Server and a Client module, where the Client displays the UI based on the data received from Server. The UI related operations happen on the OS Main thread where the GTK event loop runs. Whereas the communication with the Server happens on a non main thread. At some point, Server may send some update to the Client. The update will be received on the communication thread i.e. the non main thread. Since the intention is to update the UI (either modify the UI or Create a new window) based on the information received, somehow the information shall be passed to the OS main thread where event loop is running.

In GTK4 how to pass the information between threads (main to non-main or vice versa)?

I am deliberately avoiding g_idle_add / g_idle_timeout because it keeps running the function continuously or at regular intervals. I am looking for some GTK supported message passing mechanism without building my own message passing system.

Answer (score 1):

The callback you pass to g_idle_add needs to return `TRUE`/[`G_SOURCE_CONTINUE`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/const.SOURCE_CONTINUE.html) or `FALSE`/[`G_SOURCE_REMOVE`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/const.SOURCE_REMOVE.html). The latter will remove the function from the main loop after the first invocation so it won't be run continuously.